# Python: typecasting a variable in an object method declaration?

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm new to Python, and have a class such as the following:

```
class myclass:
    var1 = 0
    var2 = 1
    var3 = 2
    def function(self, x):
        x.method(...yadda...)
```

For this class, `x` is another object containing data and some methods, and I'd like to be able to call those methods from within an instance of `myclass`. Is there a way to specify `x` here as an object of another type? For instance, regularly one would use the following to define an object (from an imported file called `classfile`):

```
newObj = classfile.myClass()
```

For the object `x` in the code above, can I require it be of a specific object type, be it a built-in object or one I define? How would you specify this?

I would want the code to throw an error or bypass any object sent in that is not of the desired type, preferably before I start attempting to call methods in it (i.e. `x.method()`).

Comment: you can user assert isinstance(... )

Comment: Don't try to write Java in Python.

Comment: Why *before* you start attempting to call methods on it? Whether or not the object is of the *type* you're expecting, if it implements all of the methods you need what's the problem? This is [*"duck typing"*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-duck-typing), by the way.

Comment: @marcadian, thanks! That implemented what I was looking for. I'm using PyCharm (great program), and with this it shows me the object's methods properly. Unfortunately I can't seem to up-vote any responses at this point, but that definitely helped.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Could you explain? Your response is a bit vague and since I've not programmed in Java before, I'm missing the reference. I've used higher-level languages for most of my programming (Igor Pro, Matlab, etc.), done an intro to Objective-C, and from what I can tell by the Python class reference documentation the above code is how one would define a class, a method for that class, and instance variables. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Topher The point of your question is how to assert that an object is of a specified type, and my response was to indicate that you simply don't want to do that in Python. Document that your class expects an object with certain properties, but don't verify a particular type; that's missing the whole point of a dynamically-typed language like Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Ok I see what you mean. Thanks for the clarification. My main issue was that the IDE I'm using (PyCharm) wasn't handling the code properly, so perhaps the overall issue was on that end, but its good to know the problem is not one with the Python code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better practice would be to "implement" [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). So in your case

```
def function(self, x):
    try:
        x.method(... yada ...)
    except AttributeError:
        raise MyAPIError
```

Comment: In Python, duck typing just looks like `def function(self, x): x.method(...)`; it's [easier to ask forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), and if the user passed in an incompatible object they'll soon hear about it.

Comment: At the very least, you don't want to catch *every* exception, just the `AttributeError` raised if `x` doesn't actually have `method` as an attribute.

Comment: Yep, bare except is like an automatic downvote IMHO. Never a funny thing trying to debug swallowed StopIteration or SystemExit....

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as it is definitely helpful, though the comment from marcadian in my initial question is what I ultimately went with. However, I'd be curious if since as was mentioned by Daniel that typing in this way is not needed in Python, whether this is also unneeded.